# How do I turn a bootable usb thumb drive into a PXE bootable image

Tags: linux, pxe-boot

I have a USB thumb drive containing a live boot environment.

It's actually set up like a HDD with a single ext2 partition within and boots a minimal customized version of linux.

How would I go about setting this up to boot via PXE (or iPXE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a functioning PXE server, you should have no problem using [memdisk](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK#Hard_disk_images) with an image of the drive. I've used memdisk to [boot a hybrid ISO over PXE](https://serverfault.com/a/359820/42461), serving the ISO over TFTP rather than NFS.

Comment: Thanks, this is the right answer.  Now to get around the 32MB file size limit in freenas!